# Instant to-and-from Roman Numeral Conversion

Tags: converting, windows, assembly, roman-numerals, x86

**Ⅰ** [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) are composed of digits taken from a small set of uppercase characters. Lowercase characters were first used in the Middle Ages.

$$I,V,X,L,C,D,M$$

With these digits we can represent numbers from 1 to 3999.

**Ⅱ** For the benefit of representing larger numbers, one extension adds an overline or [Vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)) to the character in order to obtain a value that is a 1000 times bigger.

$$I,V,X,L,C,D,M,\overline{V},\overline{X},\overline{L},\overline{C},\overline{D},\overline{M}$$

This way the numbers can range from 1 to 3999999.

**Ⅲ** For ease of inputting and outputting, my program uses the lowercase characters as a substitute for the digits with a vinculum.

```
I=1  V= 5  C= 100  v= 5000  c= 100000
     X=10  D= 500  x=10000  d= 500000
     L=50  M=1000  l=50000  m=1000000
```

**Ⅳ** The *RomanToInteger* conversion routine tries to use as many characters as possible of the submitted string. It will stop at the first non-roman-digit character, or even sooner if such digit cannot be legally appended. The value up to that point is returned in `EAX`.
For the *IntegerToRoman* conversion routine it's much simpler. Just provide a valid number in `EAX` in the range of 1 to 3999999.

**Ⅴ** The Windows console application:

```
; Instant To and From Roman Numeral Conversion
; by MMXIX Sep Roland

        format  pe console
        include 'win32axp.inc'

        cinvoke printf, msg1
Fresh:  cinvoke printf, msg2
        call    Vitals                  ; -> EBX ESI EBP
        mov     byte [ebx+esi], 0
        cinvoke printf, msg2            ; To position the cursor
        mov     byte [ebx+esi], ' '
        jmp     Key
xKey:   cinvoke _getch                  ; Discard extended key
Key:    cinvoke _getch                  ; -> AL
        cmp     al, 0E0h
        je      xKey
        cmp     al, 0
        jz      xKey
        cmp     al, 13
        je      isRET
        cmp     al, 9
        je      isTAB
        cmp     al, 8
        je      isBS
Char:   cmp     esi, [ebp+8]            ; Field length {7,27}
        jnb     Key                     ; Field is full
        mov     ecx, [ebp+16]           ; Number of valid characters {10,13}
        lea     edi, [ebp+20]           ; List of valid characters
        repne scasb
        jne     Key                     ; Digit is invalid
        mov     [ebx+esi], al
        inc     esi
        jmp     Main_
isBS:   test    esi, esi
        jz      Key                     ; Nothing to backspace over
        dec     esi
        mov     byte [ebx+esi], ' '
        jmp     Main_
isTAB:  xor     dword [info], infoR-infoD ; Changes fields infoD/infoR
        call    Vitals                  ; -> EBX ESI EBP
        mov     eax, [ebp]              ; {' -> ',' <- '}
        mov     [form+18], eax          ; Update directional arrow
        jmp     Main
isRET:  mov     eax, [infoD+12]
        add     eax, [infoR+12]
        jz      Quit
        cinvoke printf, crlf
        call    WipeD                   ; -> EDI (AL ECX)
        call    WipeR                   ; -> EDI (AL ECX)
        jmp     Fresh
Quit:   cinvoke printf, wipe
        invoke  system, "pause>0"       ; Facilitates taking a screenshot
        invoke  exit, 0
; --------------------------------------
Main_:  mov     [ebp+12], esi           ; Current character position
Main:   cmp     dword [info], 0
        jne     InputR
; Decimal input, then calculate and show roman
InputD: call    WipeR                   ; -> EDI (AL ECX)

        xor     eax, eax                ; DecimalToInteger
        xor     esi, esi
        jmp     .b
.a:     imul    eax, 10
        movzx   edx, byte [ebx+esi]     ; EBX is address of the decimal field
        sub     dl, '0'
        add     eax, edx
        inc     esi
.b:     cmp     esi, [ebp+12]           ; Repeat for all digits
        jb      .a

        test    eax, eax
        jz      .c                      ; Invalid number
        cmp     eax, 3999999
        ja      .c                      ; Invalid number
        mov     edx, edi                ; EDI is address of the roman field
        call    IntegerToRoman          ; -> EDI
        sub     edi, edx
        mov     [infoR+12], edi         ; Number of roman digits

.c:     jmp     Fresh
; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
; Roman input, then calculate and show decimal
InputR: call    WipeD                   ; -> EDI (AL ECX)

        mov     esi, ebx                ; EBX is address of the roman field
        call    RomanToInteger          ; -> EAX ESI
        sub     esi, ebx
        cmp     esi, [ebp+12]
        jne     .c                      ; Too many characters
        test    eax, eax
        jz      .c                      ; Invalid number

        mov     ebx, 10                 ; IntegerToDecimal
        xor     ecx, ecx
.a:     xor     edx, edx
        div     ebx
        push    edx
        inc     ecx
        test    eax, eax
        jnz     .a
        mov     [infoD+12], ecx         ; Number of decimal digits
.b:     pop     eax
        add     al, "0"
        stosb                           ; EDI is address of the decimal field
        loop    .b

.c:     jmp     Fresh
; --------------------------------------
; IN () OUT (ebx,esi,ebp)
Vitals: mov     ebp, infoD
        add     ebp, [ebp-4]            ; Info select {0=infoD,32=infoR}
        mov     ebx, form
        add     ebx, [ebp+4]            ; Field offset {10,30}
        mov     esi, [ebp+12]           ; Current character position
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN () OUT (edi) MOD (al,ecx)
WipeR:  mov     edi, form
        add     edi, [infoR+4]          ; Offset to the roman field
        push    edi
        mov     ecx, [infoR+8]          ; Length of the roman field
        mov     al, ' '
        rep stosb
        pop     edi
        mov     [infoR+12], ecx         ; Number of roman digits is 0
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN () OUT (edi) MOD (al,ecx)
WipeD:  mov     edi, form
        add     edi, [infoD+4]          ; Offset to the decimal field
        push    edi
        mov     ecx, [infoD+8]          ; Length of the decimal field
        mov     al, ' '
        rep stosb
        pop     edi
        mov     [infoD+12], ecx         ; Number of decimal digits is 0
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (esi) OUT (eax,esi)
RomanToInteger:
        push    ebx ecx edx edi
        xor     eax, eax                ; EAX is value of resulting integer
        cdq                             ; EDX is value of current digit
        mov     edi, 12                 ; EDI is offset in list of characters
        mov     cl, "m"
        cmp     [esi], cl
        je      .m
        sub     edi, 2
.More:  mov     bl, cl                  ; -> BL={"m","c","x","M","C","X"}
        mov     cx, [infoR+20+edi]      ; -> CX={"cd","xl","Mv","CD","XL","IV"}
        cdq                             ; Can replace 'xor edx, edx' (EAX<4M)
        cmp     [esi], ch               ; CH={"d","l","v","D","L","V"}
        je      .dlvDLV
        cmp     [esi], cl               ; CL={"c","x","M","C","X","I"}
        jne     .OK
.cxMCXI:inc     esi
        mov     dl, 9
        cmp     [esi], bl               ; BL={"m","c","x","M","C","X"}
        je      .OK_
        mov     dl, 4
        cmp     [esi], ch               ; CH={"d","l","v","D","L","V"}
        je      .OK_
        mov     dl, 1
        jmp     .Repts
.dlvDLV:inc     esi
        mov     dl, 5
        cmp     [esi], cl               ; CL={"c","x","M","C","X","I"}
        jne     .OK
.m:     inc     esi
        inc     edx                     ; -> EDX={1,6}
.Repts: cmp     [esi], cl               ; CL={"m","c","x","M","C","X","I"}
        jne     .OK
        inc     esi
        inc     edx                     ; -> EDX={2,7}
        cmp     [esi], cl               ; CL={"m","c","x","M","C","X","I"}
        jne     .OK
        inc     edx                     ; -> EDX={3,8}
.OK_:   inc     esi
.OK:    imul    eax, 10
        add     eax, edx                ; EDX=[0,9]
        sub     edi, 2
        jns     .More
        pop     edi edx ecx ebx
        ret
; --------------------------------------
; IN (eax,edi) OUT (edi)
IntegerToRoman:
        push    eax ebx edx esi
        mov     ebx, 10                 ; Divider
        mov     esi, -2                 ; Offset in list of characters
.a:     add     esi, 2
        xor     edx, edx
        div     ebx
        push    edx
        test    eax, eax
        jnz     .a
.b:     pop     ebx                     ; -> EBX=[0,9]
        mov     dl, [codes+ebx]         ; Encoding of a multicharacter digit
        jmp     .d
.c:     movzx   ebx, dh                 ; -> EBX=[1,3]
        mov     al, [infoR+20+esi+ebx-1] ; Sets are {"m","cdm","xlc","Mvx",
        stosb                           ;               "CDM","XLC","IVX"}
.d:     mov     dh, 0
        shl     dx, 2                   ; Each non-zero bitpair selects a char
        jnz     .c                      ; from the current set of 3 characters
        sub     esi, 2
        jns     .b                      ; Go for next lower order digit
        pop     esi edx ebx eax
        ret
; --------------------------------------
        ALIGN   4
info:   dd      0                       ; {0,infoR-infoD}
 infoD: dd      ' -> ', 10, 7, 0, 10
        db      '0123456789', 0, 0
 infoR: dd      ' <- ', 30, 27, 0, 13
        db      'IVXLCDMvxlcdm'
codes:  db      00000000b
        db      01000000b
        db      01010000b
        db      01010100b
        db      01100000b
        db      10000000b
        db      10010000b
        db      10010100b
        db      10010101b
        db      01110000b
msg1:   db      'Roman Numeral Convertor', 13, 10
        db      '=======================', 13, 10
        db      ' BS  delete   I=1  V= 5  C= 100  v= 5000  c= 100000', 13, 10
        db      ' TAB toggle        X=10  D= 500  x=10000  d= 500000', 13, 10
        db      ' RET next/exit     L=50  M=1000  l=50000  m=1000000', 13, 10
        db      '----------------------------------------------------'
 crlf:  db      13, 10, 0
msg2:   db      13
 form:  db      'DECIMAL :          -> ROMAN :                             ', 0
wipe:   db      13, '                             ', 13, 0
; --------------------------------------

data import
     library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
     import  msvcrt,_getch,'_getch',\
                    exit,'exit',\
                    printf,'printf',\
                    system,'system'
end data
```

**Ⅵ** The program working:

[image: The screenshot]

**Ⅶ** My aim was to write conversion routines that don't depend on big lookup tables. Currently using only 23 bytes of conversion data. Perhaps it made the code harder to understand. Improvements?

#### A happy \$\overline{\underline{MMXX}}\$ to all!

Comment: One improvement to the question would be to include your example program output _as text_, and not as an image.